# Prove that $\text{Hom}_R (I(M)/M, I(M)) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, functors

> **Problem:** Suppose $I(M)$ is an injective hull of $R-$module $M$. Prove that each automorphism $\varphi \colon I(M) \rightarrow I(M)$ has this property if for all $x \in M, \varphi(x)=x$ then $\varphi$ is the identity function $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\text{Hom}_R (I(M)/M, I(M)) = 0$?

Could you give me some hint to solve this problem. Thank all! In this case, we work with the injective hull $I(M)$, should we use the homomorphism theorem to solve this?

Comment: This isn't true, at least "$\Leftarrow$" implication. Over $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $I(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Q}$. And $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(I(\mathbb{Q})/\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})=0$ because all elements in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ are of finite order. But there are many $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphisms without non-trivial fixed points, e.g. $x\mapsto 2x$.

Comment: @freakish I sorry, my fault. I means each automorphism.

Comment: @freakish I think the property is "if for all $x\in M, \varphi(x) = x$ then $\varphi$ is the identity".

Comment: @freakish You right! That is my mistake in translation. The property is "If for all $x\in M, \varphi(x) = x$ then $\varphi$ is the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one direction, suppose that all automorphisms $\varphi : I(M)\to I(M)$ that restrict to the identity on $M$ are the identity on $I(M)$.

Now suppose $f:I(M)/M\to I(M)$. Compose with the projection to get a morphism $g:I(M)\to I(M)$ that vanishes on $M$. Thus $h=g+id$ is the identity on $M$.

Now use that $I(M)$ is the injective hull of $M$ to get that $h$ is an automorphism.

Conclude.

The other direction has nothing to do with injective hulls and is always true : if $\hom(I(M)/M,I(M))=0$ and $\varphi$ is an automorphism that is the identity on $M$, what can you say about $\varphi-id$ ? Etc.

Comment: Could you explane more explicitly the $\Longrightarrow$ statement?

Comment: So you want more than a hint ?

Comment: I don't understand in $h = g +id$, so we get $h = g + \varphi$ in which $\varphi$ is the identity on $M$ and $g$ vanishes on $M$. So we get $h = \varphi$?

Comment: No, who would be $\varphi$ in that scenario ? $h$ is the one who becomes $\varphi$